SQL script for subtype table
In SQL, I have a table FACILITIES (FacilityID PRIMARY KEY, FacilityName, FacilityAddress, FacilityPhone, FacilyType)
FacilityType refers to subtype tables of

AFFILIATION (FacilityID PK, AffiliationStartDate, AffiliationEndDate, StaffType, AffiliationVerified);

EMPLOYER (FacilityID PK, HireDate, TermDate, Position, HRContactName)

CLIENT (FacilityID PK, ContactName, ContactEmail, ConstractStart, ContractEnd, ContractActive)


As is, the FACILITY can be 1 or more of the subtypes - which is true. A facility can be both a client and an employer. How do I write a script tying the subtypes to FACILITY?
I was thinking of a junction table but can I do that with subtype tables?

As it stands I don't see why you couldn't do normal joins here. I.e. select ... from Facilities ... left join Affiliation ... left join Employer ... left join Client ...

Subtype (or child) tables - need their own PK and the Parent PK becomes a Foreign Key allowing you to associate one or more child records to the parent.
So your subtype table definitions become:
AFFILIATION (AffiliationID PK, FacilityID FK, AffiliationStartDate, AffiliationEndDate, StaffType, AffiliationVerified);

EMPLOYER (EmployerID PK, FacilityID FK, HireDate, TermDate, Position, HRContactName)

CLIENT (ClientID PK, FacilityID FK, ContactName, ContactEmail, ConstractStart, ContractEnd, ContractActive)

Then your query becomes
SELECT * FROM
FACILITY F
AFFILIATION A LEFT OUTER JOIN F.FacilityID = A.FacilityID
EMPLOYER E LEFT OUTER JOIN F.FacilityID = E.FacilityID
CLIENT A LEFT OUTER JOIN F.FacilityID = C.FacilityID


When designing the table, how would I connect the FacilityType to the subtables?

You don't need that - just be having records in the other tables defines the type

Why can't the PK and FK be the same column? In a 1:1 relationship that's perfectly reasonable.
